# File is not evaluated when `import`

Tags: webpack, babeljs, amd, commonjs

There is a b.js

```
const test = 'test';
console.log(test);
module.exports = {test};
```

when importing a file

```
const a = require('./b');
```

I notice that `test` is not printed out unless I change the name of `b` file into something else.

Not sure why. Anyone ran into such situation before?

I am using babel/webpack.

Comment: did you change the file name when webpack in watch mode?

Comment: I think I ran into the cyclic dependency issue http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#sec_cyclic-dependencies , will switch to Babel modules. For more info, refer to http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/babel-commonjs.html